# Django request.GET.get() truncating url string

Tags: python, django, google-chrome-extension

I am sending a message from chrome extension to django app running locally using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. I am able to capture the message in the url but somehow the whole GET parameter is not being captured. For example,

```
 "GET /sensitiveApi/?text=%20%20%20%20The%20Idiots%20-%20Rainbow%20Six%20Siege%20Funny%20Moments%20&%20Epic%20Stuff%20%20We%27re%20back%20with%20some%20Rainbow%20Six%20Siege%20funny%20moments!%20All%20clips%20were%20streamed%20live%20on%20my%20Twitch:%20https://www.twitch.tv/teosgameMore%20Siege%20funny%20moments:%20https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list...Discord:%20https://discord.gg/teoTwitter:%20https://twitter.com/LAGxPeanutPwnerInstagram:%20https://www.instagram.com/photeographPeople%20in%20video:Alex:%20https://twitter.com/AlexandraRose_GKatie:%20https://www.twitch.tv/katielouise_jKatja:%20https://www.twitch.tv/katjawastakenPaddy:%20https://twitter.com/Patward96Smii7y:%20https://www.youtube.com/user/SMii7YSnedger:%20https://www.twitch.tv/snedgerStefan:%20https://twitter.com/lagxsourTortilla:%20https://twitter.com/Tortilla_NZColderMilk:%20https://www.youtube.com/user/ColderMilkColderMilk%20Twitch:%20https://www.twitch.tv/colder_milkColderMilk:%20Twitter:%20https://twitter.com/colder_milkMusic%20used:Outro:%20Come%20Back%20from%20San%20Francisco%20(Instrumental)%20by%20Rameses%20B%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBWac...%20Go%20check%20out%20his%20music!%20:)%20https://www.youtube.com/RamesesB2 HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

this is one response that I want to capture and I a doing `request.GET.get('text', '')` but all it returns is this,

```
 The Idiots - Rainbow Six Siege Funny Moments
```

How do I capture the whole GET parameter?

This is how I use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`,

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: 'GET',
        action: 'xhttp',
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sensitiveApi/?text=",
        data : text
    });
```

Comment: There's an unquoted `&` in the URL.

Comment: There's an unescaped ampersand (`&`) character in the example that you provided.  Django interprets this as the beginning of a new query parameter.  You need to escape this before sending the message to Django.

Comment: How do I rectify it? Unquoted `&` can come anywhere right? `text` here represents `YouTube` video titles and descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unescaped ampersand(&), that needs to be percent-encoded:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> print(urllib.quote('&'.encode('utf-8')))
%26
```

url(`http://www.example.com?fields=name&age`) with `&` would look like below mentioned value:

```
url = http://www.example.com?fields=name%26age
```

Comment: I added encodeURIComponent to text before sending to django server, but this seems good too. Thanks!